# Slow Query Logger Cassandra on server side in Cassandra 3.11.4

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

As per

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12403

I tried to enable slow query logging with below steps on Cassandra 3.11.4 ,
but not able to query them any idea what is the issue, or am i missing any step .

```
`/nodetool getlogginglevels
 Logger Name                                        Log Level
 ROOT                                                    INFO
 com.thinkaurelius.thrift                               ERROR
 org.apache.cassandra                                   DEBUG
 org.apache.cassandra.db                                DEBUG
 org.apache.cassandra.db.monitoring                     DEBUG


In cassandra.yaml
```

`# can be identified. Set this value to zero to disable slow query logging.
   slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 500`

`cat logback.xml`
   [deafult logback xml][1]

```
[1]: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/logback.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step is correct, you should check system.log for any logged slow queries. Also, you need to check system_traces keyspace where session and event table created.

Comment: as per , https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12403, it should log queries to debug.log , also i didn't find any slow queries in system.log either . system_traces keyspace session and event will log queries based on tracing command or by setting nodetool settraceprobability , that will log queries and query session details, what i want is queries which are taking more than 500ms to complete .

Comment: This issue fixed as JIRA and on cassandra latest version.

Comment: Query will be logged once any query will take time above 500ms. debug logs are generating on system.log itself you can use nodetool setlogginglevels.

Comment: based on my nodetool proxyhostograms i have lot of queries which are taking beyond 500 ms , still queries are not getting logged, have you tried this feature in 3.11.4 perhaps any bug with 3.11.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with version 3.11.4 found some lines are commented in the logback.xml file.
below is the right configuration for enable debug log

```
<root level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="SYSTEMLOG" />
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   <appender-ref ref="ASYNCDEBUGLOG" />  <!-- Comment this line to disable debug.log -->
<!--
   <appender-ref ref="LogbackMetrics" />
-->
</root>
```